# What's wrong with my url encoding?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, encoding

In my asp.net mvc application I created the following link:

```
http://localhost:2689/en/Formula.mvc/351702++LYS+GRONN+5G+9%252f2++fds
```

I get error 400 (bad request).

I think it blocks at the %25 (forward slash).
What am I doing wrong?

**--EDIT 3--**
I tried not encoding anything at all but rather rely on the default encoding of Url.RouteUrl().
It seems that this doesn't encode the "/" for some reason.
If I encode it myself first, I end up with the doubel encoded %252f. This gives me a bad request for some reason..
Why?!

**--EDIT 2--**
I generated the last part of the URI as follows:

1. Take the id.toString
2. Take the HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name)
3. Take the HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code)
4. String.Format("{0}--{1}--{2}") with the values from the previous parts
5. Add it as a parameter to Url.RouteUrl()

After that my action gets this parameter again, splits it at -- and HttpUtility.Decode() the values back.

I do it this way because the two last parameters are optional, but functional parameters. IF they are defined in a previous step, they have to be carried along to the other pages.
Less abstract: A color can have multiple names, but if a user selected it by a particular name, it should be kept throughout all the other pages.

**--EDIT 1--**
It also looks like HttpUtility.UrlEncode() and Url.Encode() return different results :S

If I don't encode the "/", it acts as a separator=>no luck there.
If I encode it with Url.Encode() I end up with %2F => Code 400
If I encode it with HttpUtility.UrlEncode() I end up with %25 => code 400

Because 400 doesn't even let it through to asp.net-mvc, the route debugger is of no use :(

Comment: What is it meant to represent? Should it be 351702++LYS+GRONN+5G+9%2f2f2++fds

Comment: It should be 351702++LYS GRONN 5G 9/2++fds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was there a couple of days ago. If you can accept unreadable route-values in the URL try this:
[URL-encoded slash in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url)

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, only I exchanged the unescapable values to words. E.g.: "-slash-". Not what I call perfect, but it's the best I can come up with for now.

Answer (score 2):

`%25` is actually encoded "%", so `%252f` is encoded  "%2f".

`%2f` (encoded "/") is not allowed in URL unless you explicitly allow it in webserver's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the Routing debugger: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked too much at the encoding - but note that if this is to be *stored* somewhere (or acted upon in some way), then a POST would be more appropriate. If the text on the right is actually representative of the data with id 351702 (a vanity url, much like `/665354/whats-wrong-with-my-url-encoding`), then you should humanize the text. Much as the spaces have been removed from the above. It is also common to have this as a separate level in the route that is simply discarded.

Generally, MVC urls should be comprehensible.

Comment: This part of the url defines first the id of a color. Then the two parts after that are optional to define the prefered name and code. It has to be sent throughout the application.
I am aiming to be RESTfull, not at making the URL a human interface. Which is a silly idea in my opinion.

Comment: Also, there's no storing involved. I know about the dangers of making any data changing available through get.

Comment: I now get what you mean with keeping the ID appart from the description. In my case the description isn't just for SEO. It has a functional purpose. Because of the way my source database works (I can't change it) the description is the key of something.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a forward slash as a value in the URL. Here is a nice post about creating browser and SEO friendly URLS => http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/displayBlog.aspx?id=34

[Edit]
Whenever you create a route you associate it with a URL pattern (The default pattern is {controller}/{action}/{id}). And in this url pattern you are supposed to use the forward slash to separate different tokens. Hope that helps

Comment: So what's the alternative then? And why isn't URL encode catching this?

Comment: Yes you can. It's only the default configuration, that doesn't allow it.

Comment: Whenever you create a route you associate it with a URL pattern (The default pattern is {controller}/{action}/{id}). And in this url pattern you are supposed to use the forward slash to separate different tokens. Hope that helps.

Comment: %252F is not / its *double* encoded slash. There is no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: You are right, Whatever I said is right just for the "Forward Slash" character, It should work for the "%" character just fine. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools works fine: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/html_form_submit.asp?text=hello/world

Here's the URL encoding reference: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: the query string can indeed. But this is not part of the querystring. Nor can I make it part of it.