# Bad request 400 for HttpUtility.UrlEncoded URL segments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So, if there are url encoded segments in my apps MVC url, IIS throws a BAD REQUEST 400.

e.g. 
http://u.lasoo.com.au/Offer/*9289--750W-Generic-ATX12V-Power-Supply-%252449dot99/6355

<--- the '*' and '%' are causing this error.

Notice that http://u.lasoo.com.au/Offer/The-Giant-Good-As-Gone-7-Day-Sale/6354 works fine.

What's the correct way to convert an arbitrary string into an accepted MVC URL segment?

UPDATE: the URl segment should resemble the original string. Base64 encoding completely transformed the string.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url

Comment: Thanks, but Base64 transforms the string too much

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the info in the url you can pass it as a get parameter. Like this:

```
http://u.lasoo.com.au/Offer/?id=*9289--750W-Generic-ATX12V-Power-Supply-%252449dot99/6355
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried UrlEncode? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

Try a string replace to strip out or substitute symbols ":", "%", "*", "/" - any symbols illegal within a folder name. They seem to screw up everything royally and appear to be a design weakness of the URL routing system.

Comment: This isn't about the folder names, but the routes, so doing a string replace would not necessarily be the best solution.