# Properly url encode space character

Tags: asp.net-mvc, urlencode

I use HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode any value that is used in a route.

I already solved an issue with encoding forward slashes. The new problem I have now is with spaces. A space is encoded as + .

This works on the VS integrated Webserver, but I have an issue with it in IIS7 on Windows Server 2008. 
If I have the URL `http://localhost/Home/About/asdas+sdasd`

I get the error 404.11 - Request contains double escape sequence.

I know I can just replace the space by "%20", but I dont want to care about propper encoding myself. Is there any ready to use UrlEncoder for MVC out there?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

' ' encoded to %20 use `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode`.

Comment: This may have changed, but the documentation for UrlPathEncode now says: `Do not use; intended only for browser compatibility. Use System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(System.String).`

Comment: However, if you use UrlEncode you still get spaces encoded as +.  And UrlPathEncode does not encode # either, so they are both broken.

Answer (score 0):

Any URL Encoding is *most often* designed to work on the path component of the url, the reason because different schemes have different characters in the safe list. Look for your libraries urlencoder and just use it in the path and above portion of the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
@HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(path)
```

UrlPathEncode just encodes the path of the Url, rather than encoding the whole Url.