# Query string with slashes "/" not working in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, query-string

I have a special case here: 
My action method accepts one parameter, this parameter is expected to be a full url (e.g. http://www.somesite.com/article/onesite?hello=whatever&etc=blah). When working with old asp.net (oh, excuse me guys, I mean web forms) this works just fine, but when using asp.net mvc and preparing the required route ("/myaction/{inputUrl" with no constraints on inputUrl) it fails. If the url has any slashes I get an "Bad Request" exception. What should I do? Should I add a regex constraint on the passed in url to match a web url? What do you think dear SO Gus?

***PS: The resource will be requested from an iPhone app, which means, I don't have any control over the coming url (i.e. I can't encode it!)***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to html.encode the querystring before sending?

Comment: actually the request will come from an iPhone app, i don't have control of encoding the url before sending it!

Comment: then use encodeURIComponent to encode it with javascript

Answer (score 1):

See this question [URL-encoded slash in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url).

Even UrlEncode will not help here. The behaviour changes in MVC2.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your route as `/myaction/{*inputURL*}`. This will catch all after myaction.

Comment: I already have a catch-all route set to something else. I can't have more than one catch-all routes.