# how will you do this in MVC custom route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

www.yoursite.com/image/http://images.google.com.ph/images/nav_logo7.png

What I need to know here is the Controller Action, and the Global.asax routes

Comment: Give us a clue... what language?! what framework / platform etc etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The colon `:` character is not valid in the path segment of the URL, so you'll have to either encode it, or remove it entirely. After that, you can use the `{*routeValue}` syntax to specify that the route value should be assigned the remainder of the URL.

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    "Image", 
    "image/{*url}", 
    new { controller = "Image", action = "Index" } 
);
```

For the url `http://www.yoursite.com/image/images.google.com.ph/images/nav_logo7.png`
, the above route will execute `ImageController.Index()` with a `url` argument of `"images.google.com.ph/images/nav_logo7.png"`. How you choose to deal with the protocol (encode/remove) is up to you.

Also keep in mind that a url authority can be made up of a domain name and a port number, separated by `:` (www.google.com:80) which would also need to be encoded.

Comment: `:` is not your only problem, there are many more reserved characters like `!  * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]`. How do you guarantee they are not in the URL? You should use a full UrlEncode over entire URL. You can then convert %2F back to `/` if it needs to be preety

Comment: My original answer assumed that the requirement dealt with URIs that were already deemed valid. As such, no additional encoding would be required.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to send a URL as a parameter on a URL you need to [URL Encode](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) it first

In c# use `Server.UrlEncode(string)` from the `System.Web` namespace

So your example will look like:

```
www.yoursite.com/image/http%3a%2f%2fimages.google.com.ph%2fimages%2fnav_logo7.png
```

And your route pattern could be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "image",
    "image/{url}",
    new { controller = "Image", action = "Index", url = "" }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by not trying to embed a second URL into your route.

In cases where I have to use a URL as part of a route, I replace the slashes with an alternate character so you don't have issues with the interpertation of the URL as a malformed route (i.e.~,|,etc.) then retranslate these with some string replaces in the controller.  And if possible, I'd ditch the HTTP:// and assume the route is a URL by convention.

So your route would become something like:

www.yoursite.com/image/images.google.com.ph~images~nav_logo7.png

Answer (score 0):

[URL-encoded slash in URL - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url)

This is same problem and solved solutions.

1st solution.
 Replace "://" to "/". Routing url pattern "image/{scheme}/{port}/{*url}".

2nd solution
 "image/{*url}" set *url value base64.