# Encrypted String originates 404 error in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On ASP.NET MVC 5.1 I have an action which receives an encrypted string, for example:

Nf7JnWp/QXfA9MNd52RxKpWg=

But I get a 404 error because of the slash inside this string ...

I tried to encode the string with HttpUtility.UrlEncode and WebUtility.UrlEncode;

But I keep having the same problems. Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Thank You,

Miguel

Comment: So if you pass a string without a `/`, do you get routed to the right action or do you get a 404?

Comment: I get routed to the right action ...

Comment: Can you provide the rendered link from your source?

Comment: Yes, I tried the following @Html.ActionLink("Test", MVC.User.Remove(WebUtility.UrlEncode("L22llNf7JnWp/QXfA9MNd52RxKpWg="))) and the rendered url is "localhost:8580/remover/l22llnf7jnwp%252fqxfa9mnd52rxkpwg%253d" and I get the error "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%)." If I type it to the url bar I get a 404 error

Comment: Instead of passing it via a URL segement, can you try a querystring (using the name of your action parameter: localhost:8580/remover?ID=l22llnf7jnwp%252fqxfa9mnd52rxkpwg%253d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a workaround for this by defining a custom route. Now I do not know how you named your controller or your action, so I'll use generic names.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SpecialControllerName",
    "CustomName/{*id}",
     new { controller = "CustomName", action = "CustomAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

public ActionResult Name(string id)
{
  //logic goes here

}
```

So what we did here, is take the action out of the equation. Now if you call `http://yourdomain.com/CustomName/Nf7JnWp/QXfA9MNd52RxKpWg=` it will call the Action method `CustomName` in the Controller `CustomNameController`.

Please note, that the asp.net Framework takes the first route in your route config, which matches its patterns. If you have your Defaultroute and place your new custom route *below* it, it will fail. Placing the Custom route above it, will work

Similar questions on SO:

1. [ActionLink contains slash ('/') and breaks link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140867/actionlink-contains-slash-and-breaks-link/22141046#22141046)
2. [URLs with slash in parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328713/asp-net-mvc-urls-with-slash-in-parameter)