# Passing ID to the URL when ID starts with "/"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

For example we want to edit a person and his URL is like

```
 person/id
```

but what if the value of that ID is something like **"/34555P3"**

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC: URLs with slash in parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328713/asp-net-mvc-urls-with-slash-in-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then it should be URL-encoded:

```
person/%2F34555P3
```

Since the type of the `id` in the routing/actions would clearly need to be a `string`, it will automatically be URL-decoded by the framework when determining its value.  In most cases the framework will automatically URL-encode it for you when you use it as a route value in things like `Html.ActionLink()` or `Url.Action()`.  Anywhere that you use the value manually you may need to encode it manually.

Comment: even if we have used Attributed Routing, still it should be smart enough to URL-encode it?

Comment: @DevWannaBe: It should, yes.  The mechanism for determining the route is separate form the mechanism for encoding/decoding URL values.  It would only break the route if you manually built the URL without encoding.