# ASP.NET: route parameter with backslash "\" in url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6328713/4746087), I have problems with a backslash in my route parameter. The parameter presents a windows folder and subfolder structure, which contains backslashes.

However, every browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE) converts the backslash automatically to a slash.

```
Controller/Action/Myfolder\Mysubfolder\AnotherSubfolder
```

Always becomes:

```
Controller/Action/Myfolder/Mysubfolder/AnotherSubfolder
```

Comment: use POST body to send Mysubfolder\AnotherSubfolder parameter

Comment: `The parameter presents a windows folder and subfolder structure, which contains backslashes.` - forward slashes are the convention for representing directory structures on the web. Just use a catch-all route and convert them. Have you *ever* seen a URL with backslashes in it?

Comment: Just for awareness: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_traversal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The parameter presents a windows folder and subfolder structure, which
>   contains backslashes.

Encode the parameter and add it in the URL, in your controller you can decode it back to original value.

Encode your value using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);`

Decode it like `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value);`