# How to create a string for @Html.ActionLink that concatenates an integer from the Model and a string

Tags: model-view-controller, html.actionlink

I'm using VS2015, MVC 5 design model.  Creating a link that says "View" to open a PDF file in a new browser tab.  It works fine, but the document sub-directory is hard-coded in the controller.  I need to pass the document sub-directory + filename to the controller. The document sub-directory is the same as the Model.id .  I'm having a difficult time converting the Model.id to a string and concatenating with the filename.
The following code in the view works fine with the hard-coded sub-directory in the controller

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewAttachedDoc", "Documents", new { filename = item.filename}, new { target = "_blank" })</td>
```

But this code does not work

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewAttachedDoc", "Documents", new { filename = Convert.ToString(Model.id) + "\" + item.filename }, new { target = "_blank" })</td>
```

The controller action is:

```
    public FileResult ViewAttachedDoc(string filename)
    {
        string DocPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocPath"];
        string path = Path.Combine(DocPath, filename);
        return File(path, "application/pdf");
    }
```

TIA,
Tracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely from trying to pass a backslash through the URL. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110058/asp-net-route-parameter-with-backslash-in-url) of a similar question has that same problem and their solution was to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value);`. Otherwise if that still doesn't work, what error are you getting?
P.S. C# automatically converts / -> \ for retrieving files.

Comment: Thank you for that clue!  All I did was change: 

     <td>@Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewAttachedDoc", "Documents", new { filename = Convert.ToString(Model.id) + "\" + item.filename }, new { target = "_blank" })</td>

to:


to:
      <td>@Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewAttachedDoc", "Documents", new { filename = Convert.ToString(Model.id) + "/" + item.filename }, new { target = "_blank" })</td>

The controller "automagically" converts the "/" to "\"