# Default area route not working in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I added the default controller and action name but still the default routing is not working for the area. Here is my code:

AreaRegistration.cs

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller ="LogIn", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

RouteConfig.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When i go to http://webapplocal/admin/ i get the below error:
403 forbidden: A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Comment: thanks for the edit

Comment: might be case sensitive. Try /Admin/  Though I don't understand why you are not mapping it inside RouteConfig

Comment: @steve Routes are not case sensitive.

Comment: Why should i add it to RouteConfig? Whenever i create a new area a new routing class is generated..can u please explain ur point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true; in RouteConfig.cs and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a similar problem I ran into: [ASP.NET MVC 4 Parameters Separated by Forward Slashes "/" not passing args properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624396/asp-net-mvc-4-parameters-separated-by-forward-slashes-not-passing-args-prope)

I'd recommend adding the MapRoute into the same location as the default MapRoute, in RouteConfig.asax. This is because the routing is order-sensitive and your separate routing routine may never be looked at when the first routing fails.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller ="LogIn", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: still getting the same error after trying ur solution

Comment: Oops. I actually have it without {controller} - updated.

Comment: how come u have it without a controller lol? now all my views under Admin give 404 :D

Comment: in a mtg - may have made mistakes

Comment: I changed it back. I tested using a different Controller and it's working for me. Can you provide the code for your LoginController.cs?