# Id with / causes problems with routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, ravendb

I'm playing around with Raven DB and MVC 2.
By default, the id in Raven will be e.g. "suggestions/1234" for an entity called Suggestion.

This causes problems with routing when I write like this:

```
<%: Url.Action("Delete", "Suggestion", new { id = suggestion.Id }) %>
```

The url will be /Suggestion/Delete/suggestions/14337 which won't work.

Can this be solved in the routing, or do I have to change the format of the id in Raven? And how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your route from `{controller}/{action}/{id}` to `{controller}/{action}/{*id}`. This is called a "catch-all" route; more details [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Alternatively, you could pass the `id` as a query parameter.

Comment: Good idea but only works on the last parameter

Answer (score 0):

You will not be  able to encode the forward slash by default.

Change the id to suggestions_1234 or try to use this setting:

```
<uri> 
    <schemeSettings>
        <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
    </schemeSettings>
</uri>
```

I did not check if the config setting works yet. And I can't do it right now because the soccer starts in 5min.

[URL-encoded slash in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url)