# WebApi / Routing with URL Encoding

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-web-api, encoding, asp.net-web-api-routing

Related to this: [URL-encoded slash in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url)

I used Mehrdad Afshari's answer (wildcard route param) which works mostly! However, multiple slashes are converted to a single slash.

My route is `resource/{*url}`

With `GET resource/abc%2fdef` my controller method is called with `abc/def`.

With `GET resource/abc%2f%2f%2f%2fdef` my controller method is again called with `abc/def`. The extra slashes are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see this stackoverflow question plus solution:

[URL-encoded slash in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url)

this directs you to that post 
http://gathadams.com/2009/01/06/allowing-special-characters-forward-slash-hash-asterisk-etc-in-aspnet-mvc-urls/

Phil haacked responded like this
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/04/10/upcoming-changes-in-routing.aspx#68032

Comment: I did. I desperately hoped there might be a workaround! It looks like there isn't so I will mark this as the correct answer as it is a good summary of the issue.

Comment: Yeah actually me too ... working with a slug that remove or replaces all exceptional stuff...