# Passing a value containing a forwardslash to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Order", "OrderProduct", 
new { controller = "Orders", id = item.ITEMID }, 
new { @class = "lightbox order-link" })
```

My `item.ITEMID` id could contain a forwardslash, for example: `GT25-1/VS`

But when I click on the link, the `id` in my controller is only `GT25-1`

```
public ActionResult OrderProduct(string id)
```

Is there a way I can encode this value to include everything and then decode it in my action?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your id when creating your url, e.g.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Order", "OrderProduct", 
new { controller = "Orders", id = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.ITEMID) }, 
new { @class = "lightbox order-link" })
```

you might need/want to decode in your action then

```
id = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(id);
```