# ASP.NET Normalizing Backslashes to Forward Slashes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

ASP.NET is 'normalizing' backslashes in requests paths to forward slashes, and I need them to come through as backslashes (it is used to perform a look-up in the database). I don't mind if escaped forward-slashes come through as unescaped, unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url).

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "TransactionsApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/transactions/{*transaction}",
    defaults: new { controller = "transactions", transaction = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

*Note that I have set up transaction to match the remainder of the path.*

I tried the following URLs (both from a browser and Fiddler):

- `api/transactions/mscorlib.pdb\DFA83312EAB84F67BD225058B188F22B1\mscorlib.pdb`
- `api/transactions/mscorlib.pdb\\DFA83312EAB84F67BD225058B188F22B1\\mscorlib.pdb`
- `api/transactions/mscorlib.pdb%5CDFA83312EAB84F67BD225058B188F22B1%5Cmscorlib.pdb`
- `api/transactions/mscorlib.pdb%5C%5CDFA83312EAB84F67BD225058B188F22B1%5C%5Cmscorlib.pdb`

By the time they hit my Web API method they are all `mscorlib.pdb/DFA83312EAB84F67BD225058B188F22B1/mscorlib.pdb`. I inspected the current `HttpContext` and it looks like ASP.NET is doing this normalization (not MVC4).

Possible solutions:

- When inserting transaction normalize '\' to '/' so that no matter what ASP.NET passes through the look-up will succeed. *Seems a bit smelly*
- [Base64](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/04/09/upcoming-changes-in-routing.aspx#68032) the `{*transaction}` part if it contains a backslash. *Not really address-bar hackable*

Any idea on how to get ASP.NET to **not** do this normalization?

Comment: **NOT** a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

You cannot prevent this behavior as it is hard-coded into IIS.

### Investigation

I wanted to investigate this issue by decompiling the runtime and following the code. It's always nice to do that: you learn how the runtime works and sometimes you find the problem. Let's start the journey...

As a starting point, I'm decompiling System.Web with ILSpy, starting at the HttpRuntime class. Navigating through `public static void ProcessRequest(HttpWorkerRequest wr)`, `ProcessRequestNoDemand`, `ProcessRequestNow`, `ProcessRequestInternal`...

Here I want to investigate the following lines:
`httpContext = new HttpContext(wr, false);`,
`httpContext.Response.InitResponseWriter();`,
`httpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(httpContext,  this._handlerCompletionCallback, httpContext);`.

In `HttpContext.HttpContext(HttpWorkerRequest wr, bool initResponseWriter)` many things may cause this:
`this.Init(request, response)`,
`new HttpRequest(wr, this)`.

More precisely `HttpContext.GetEurl()` (looks suspicious),
`Request.InternalRewritePath(VirtualPath.Create(virtualPath), null, true)` (safe),
`VirtualPath.Create(virtualPath)`  (looks very suspicious),
`virtualPath = UrlPath.FixVirtualPathSlashes(virtualPath);` (the infamous!).

Let's write the stack trace that gets us here:

- `HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest...` (multiple methods)
- `new HttpContext(wr, false)`
- `this.Init(new HttpRequest(wr, this), new HttpResponse(wr, this));`
- `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eurl))` (can we prevent entering the if?)
- `this.Request.InternalRewritePath(VirtualPath.Create(virtualPath), null, true);`
- `VirtualPath Create(string virtualPath)`
- `unsafe static VirtualPath Create(string virtualPath, VirtualPathOptions options)`

This last (unsafe) method is doing something to the path. First there is a loop over each character. If a char is below '.', and is different from '/' and is equal to '\', then `flag = true`. After the loop, `if (flag)` ([src](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/VirtualPath.cs,604)), then an exception may be thrown, and `virtualPath = UrlPath.FixVirtualPathSlashes(virtualPath);` ([src](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/VirtualPath.cs,610)).

Is seems for now that nothing will help us avoid going there (maybe the eurl thing?).

The `string FixVirtualPathSlashes(string virtualPath)` ([src](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/UrlPath.cs,318)) replaces the backslashes into slashes and if removes the duplicate slashes. Shame.

What about the `GetEurl` method? When you read [src](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpContext.cs,519), you find that is will not help you.

#### Conclusion

The http runtime is killing your backslashes for no documented reason. There is no way you can disable this behavior.

### Workaround #1

Now, there must be a way. [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33801447/282105) referencing [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/iis-rewrite-rule-when-committer-name-contains-backslashes-695110056.html) has a workaround. It seems that using the rewrite module, you can put the original URL back into the pipeline. I don't really like this solution because I don't know what's going on exactly. I have another idea...

I did not yet test this thing. Can you?

### Searching for workaround #2 (none found)

What if there was a place where the original request path was stored?

Searching `HttpRequest`, none of the `Url.OriginalString`, `RawUrl`, `Path`, `ServerVariables` contains the desired value. Not even the `_filePath`, `_path`, `_queryStringText`, `_rawUrl`, `_rewrittenUrl`, `_url` private fields.

Search into the `IIS7WorkerRequest`, the value is already changed at runtime. I suspect IIS is doing the thing *before* pushing the request to the ASP.NET runtime. It looks like there is no hope.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the original URL via the UNENCODED_URL server variable:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["UNENCODED_URL"]
```

Backslashes will appear as "%5C" in this URL.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried applying UrlEncode() to the path before making the request?

Comment: Yes he did. It's written.