# How to prevent IIS not to change backslashes with forward slashes

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, urlencode

I am using WebAPI2 and I have a route "Products/{Id}/details".
When Id contains \ , IIS changes it to **/**. 
For example **pr\p** is changed to **pr/p** and it "spoils" the uri.
I want to know how to prevent changing **** to **/**, or are there any other workarounds?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's probably your Browser manipulating the url, not IIS.

Comment: I have checked it using developer tools and convinced that my browser doesn't manipulate the url.

Comment: Check the actual url used in the "Network" panel of your developer tools. I assume that "\" is invalid in a url. If need to encode it as `%5C`.

Comment: @SargisKoshkaryan did you find a solution w/o hacking with urlrewrite?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHKB/IIS+rewrite+rule+when+committer+name+contains+backslashes) looks useful:

```
<rule name="KeepBackslashes" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://HOST:PORT/{UrlDecode:{C:1}}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{UNENCODED_URL}" pattern="/(.*?)($|\?)" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```