# Query string parameter vs regular parameter ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, query-string

I have been working on desktop applications mostly and thought to learn web development using ASP.Net MVC5 and thus going through the book by [Jon Galloway](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118794753.html). So I was reading about how you can pass the parameters to action methods using query string like

> /Store/Browse?genre=Disco

or directly embed them in the url like

> /Store/Details/5

Now the controller code that I wrote (taken from book) is below :

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Store
        public string Index()
        {
            return "Hello from Store.Index()";
        }

        public string Browse(string genre)
        {
            string message = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Store.Browser, Genre = " + genre);
            return message;
        }

        public string Details(int id)
        {
            string message = "Store.Details, ID = " + id;
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

The url opens fine and the actions return the message as expected. But just to try I tried to pass the genre value by embedding it in the url like

> /Store/Browse/Rap

but that doesn't work like it did for the Details() action. I thought it may have to do something with the datatype of genre, so I tried changing the data type of id in Details() to string as below :

```
public string Details(string id)
        {
            string message = "Store.Details, ID = " + id;
            return message;
        }
}
```

and opened the url

> /Store/Details/5

and the Details() action returns message with id value 5, but when i do the same for Browse() action

> /Store/Browse/Rap

the action doesn't return the message with genre value "Rap". I tried to pass the genre value and removed the html encoding to see if that had anything to do with it, but it didn't.

I looked at the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url) but that didn't help either. Any comments appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your using the `Default` route which is defined as

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

and expects a value for `id`. When you use `/Store/Browse/Rap`, then the value of the 3rd segment ("Rap") will be bound to a paramater named `id`, but your `Browse()` method does not contain one (its named `genre`).

Either change the name of the parameter so its

```
public string Browse(string id)
```

and the value of `id` will be "Rap",

**Or** create a specific route definition and place it before the `Default` route (and keep the `Browse()` method as is)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Browse",
    url: "Store/Browse/{genre}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Store", action = "Browse", genre = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
... // default route here
```

Side note: You do not need to change the type of the parameter in the `Details` method if your always passing a value that is a valid `int`

Comment: Thanks, that explains the confusion.